# phpmyadmin-problem with pmadb configuration

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have problems with my phpmyadmin. I upgraded it to 5 today, removed the latest version, but I still have problems to make any rights for all or new DB or in phpmyadmin-db.

The system write me first of all **one general problem that I could not solve Konfiguration "des pmadb… fehlerhaft Dokumentation
Allgemeine Verknüpfungsfunktionen Deaktiviert
Eine Datenbank mit Namen „phpmyadmin“ anlegen und dort die phpMyAdmin-Konfigurationsspeicher-Tabellen einrichten".**

It was created phpmyadmin but do not know how I can make phpMyAdmin-Konfigurationsspeicher-Tabellen.

If I tried to make the right for a new DB I got this error:

```
SQL-Befehl: Kopieren DokumentationBearbeiten Bearbeiten

(
                SELECT `User`, `Host`, `Select_priv`,
            `Insert_priv`,
            `Update_priv`,
            `Delete_priv`,
            `Create_priv`,
            `Drop_priv`,
            `Grant_priv`,
            `Index_priv`,
            `Alter_priv`,
            `References_priv`,
            `Create_tmp_table_priv`,
            `Lock_tables_priv`,
            `Create_view_priv`,
            `Show_view_priv`,
            `Create_routine_priv`,
            `Alter_routine_priv`,
            `Execute_priv`,
            `Event_priv`,
            `Trigger_priv`, '*' AS `Db`, 'g' AS `Type`
                FROM `mysql`.`user`
                WHERE NOT (BINARY `Select_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `Insert_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `Update_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `Delete_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `Create_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `Drop_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `Grant_priv` = 'N' AND
            BINARY `References_priv` = 'N' A[...]
MySQL meldet: Dokumentation
#1030 - Fehler 176 "Read page with wrong checksum" von Speicher-Engine Aria
```

Could anyone help me with this or five any good suitable information?